# Angular data binding conditional inside ngIf

Tags: angular

I am trying to display recipes within a certain food category, but not having luck. I am looping this through an array of recipes inside a parent component.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8" *ngIf="{{ recipe.category }} === mexican">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ recipe.name }}</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ recipe.description }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
      <img src="{{ recipe.imagePath }}" alt="{{ recipe.name }}" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
```

Comment: Try this: `*ngIf="recipe.category === 'mexican'"`.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is not clear, i hope the code snippet might work.

```
<div class="row">
  <ng-container  *ngIf="recipe.category === 'mexican'">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ recipe.name }}</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ recipe.description }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <img [src]="recipe.imagePath" [attr.alt]="{{ recipe.name }}" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```